# How do I find the maximum value of $e^{-x^2+x}\cos(x^3+4)\cdot(x^4)$?

Tags: calculus, mathematical-physics, computational-mathematics

I've put it through symbolab to derivate and obtained:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}=e^{-x^2+x}(-2x+1)\cos(x^3+4)x^4+[-3x^6\sin(x^3+4)+4x^3\cos(x^3+4)]e^{-x^2+x}=0
$$
and then simplified to:
$$
\frac{-2x^2+x+4}{3^3}=\tan(x^3+4)
$$
Where can I go from here, if at all?
(I apologize for any mistakes in my englsih)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get it

Comment: There is a typo : $3^3$ should be $3x^3$